# Recoger información de bash con GoLang

Tags: go, pipe

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación que imprima un comando en bash, y después recoger la información que muestra el terminal, el problema es que la información se muestra por pantalla pero no soy capaz de recogerla
Al final de todo hago un fmt.Println(text) para comprobar si tiene algo guardado.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    cmdString, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }

    cmdString = strings.TrimSuffix(cmdString, "\n")
    arrCommandStr := strings.Fields(cmdString)
    cmd := exec.Command(arrCommandStr[0], arrCommandStr[1:]...)
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Run()

    text := cmd.Stdin.Read
    fmt.Println(text)

}
```

El mesange que saca al ajecutar el comando "ls -l" es el seguiente:

```
ls -l
total 2168
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 martin martin 2212451 Jun 11 13:58 goBash
-rw-rw-r--. 1 martin martin     902 Jun 11 13:48 goBash.go
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x49f611]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /home/martin/golang/src/goBash/goBash.go:26 +0x2f1
```

antes de que salte el error, muestra por pantalla el comando, pero lo que busco es poder recogerlo en una variable String, no mostrarlo.
Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el package [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) para ejecutar comandos y la función `Output()` para obtener el resultado.

```
out, err := exec.Command("ls", "-l").Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
result := string(out);
```